# how to use chosen but still allow input of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen to display a single select out of a long list of options.

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

I would also like to be able to allow the user to submit a choice that is not already in the list of options.

This is only meant for single select.

Right now, when there is no match in any options for what the user keys in, the chosen will clear away the typed input when focus leaves the chosen textbox.

Advise me on how to alter chosen for this purpose. Or if there is another tool that allows me to achieve the same effect, I'll be interested to know.

Answer (score 1):

You may call a javascript function triggered by "enter" button to get the value inputted by the user and call your own search function

```
$('.chosen-search').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('.searchBtn').trigger('click');
    }
});


$('.searchBtn').click(function() {
    extraSearchString = $('.chosen-search input[type="text"]').val();
    searchStringNotInList(extraSearchString);
}
```

In this case, you may process any string inputted by the user when he/she clicks the search button or clicks "enter"

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the, ahem, chosen way but you could add an 'other' option to the select element and when it's selected, reveal a free text input to the user.

Comment: Instead of revealing another text input, I was hoping to use the same text input chosen automatically conjured up. Possible? Or another plugin?

Comment: You might want to check out Select2. It allows what you're looking for. http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ and search for "createSearchChoice"

Comment: Thank you, I will try Select2 in that case